# How to use case when expression in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

In HQL, i have used following query.

```
queryBuilder.append("SELECT cc FROM com.atulsia.core.model.CoupenCode as cc WHERE cc.segment.id = -1 or "
                    +" ( CASE WHEN (cc.category.id == "+product.getCategory().getId()+") THEN cc.subCategory.id = -1  ELSE NULL  END ) or"
                    +" cc.subCategory.id = "+product.getSubCategory().getId()+" and cc.status.statusId = 9");
```

But i am getting exception.

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: =
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `cc.category.id == `... is not valid. Have you tried with only one `=` sign ?

Comment: yes i tried with with single = but same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HQL` query has two errors:

```
queryBuilder.append(
    "SELECT cc FROM com.atulsia.core.model.CoupenCode as cc 
    WHERE cc.segment.id = -1 or "
    +" ( CASE WHEN (cc.category.id == "+product.getCategory().getId()+") THEN cc.subCategory.id = -1  ELSE NULL  END ) or"
    +" cc.subCategory.id = "+product.getSubCategory().getId()+" and cc.status.statusId = 9");
```

Equals in `HQL` is the same of `SQL` so you must use one `=` and not `==`

The second:

```
CASE WHEN (cc.category.id == "+product.getCategory().getId()+")
THEN cc.subCategory.id = -1 <--- You can't assign here

and in ELSE you put NULL.
```

Aren't congruent

**Solution**

```
    "SELECT cc FROM com.atulsia.core.model.CoupenCode as cc " +
    " WHERE cc.segment.id = -1 or " +
    "cc.subCategory.id = " +
        " (CASE " + 
           " WHEN (cc.category.id = "+product.getCategory().getId() + ")" +
           " THEN -1 ELSE cc.subCategory.id  END ) or " +
    " cc.subCategory.id = "+product.getSubCategory().getId()+ " and cc.status.statusId = 9"
```